# Clockspeed graphing program in linux

Tags: cpu-frequency, plotting

Is there a program to graph (CPU) clockspeeds in real time? For example, something like psensor which is useful for temperature graphs.

EDIT: Running Fedora 27 on a Ryzen system (Pinnacle Ridge)

Comment: matlab can do it

Comment: @ajeh I'm looking for a monitoring utility, not a general plotting software.

Comment: Please add these details to the question. Did you google at all? If you did, what in this solution is missing for your use case: https://olausson.de/programs/plot-linux-system-stats ?

Comment: @ajeh i7z seems to be just for Intel systems. I edited my post to mention I'm using AMD.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit overkill for just plotting CPU frequencies, but [Netdata](http://my-netdata.io/) can do this with minimal setup effort (install it, start it collecting data, and point a web browser at the dashboard).  It also provides a mind boggling variety of other statistics in real (or near real) time, including networking data, temperature sensor data, general system performance info, and even per-user stats, with a comparatively miniscule overhead (typically less than 1% CPU utilization despite collecting data every second, and double digit MB memory usage with default settings on most systems).

Comment: Incredible! Can it run just the CPU part? Even though the service is lightweight, a browser with the visualizations might not be.

Comment: Actually, it's reporting only base clocks, not also boost clocks. I just tested it on a Ryzen 2700X, and netdata is showing max 3.7GHz, while `lscpu`shows up to 4.3GHz. Maybe a configuration issue?

Comment: Hmm, I think that's a bug in netdata then, not a configuration issue.  I've not looked too far into the cpufreq plugin myself, so i'm not sure.